# Passport AngularJS ExpressJS: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

When I'm trying to use $http module of angular.js for authorizing twitter app I always get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=something. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Client Code:

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   headers: { "Content-Type": undefined },
   url: '/oauth/twitter'
});
```

Server Code:

```
app.configure(function () {
   app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'tobo!', cookie: { maxAge: 3600 }}));

   app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret'}));
   app.use(passport.initialize());
   app.use(passport.session());
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});

app.get('/oauth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'), function (req, res) {
// The request will be redirected to Twitter for authentication, so this
// function will not be called.
console.log('ouath/twitter')
});

app.get('/oauth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { successRedirect:  '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

But it works ok if I use a hyperlink with oauth/twitter address. I don't know what is the problem. Most said that origin is not allowed, but '*' should allow every address to be connected to server.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't find a solution! have you solved the problem?

Comment: I also have the same problem. But when you say using hyperlink directly worked, how did you exclude it in the routeProvider? Did you load it outside angular app? Sorry if this question is too trivial, I am just a newbie to angular & passport & expressjs

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing same issue with backbonejs

Comment: I had a similar issue. I even had a direct hyperlink to oauth/twitter but it gave me a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. Turns out jquerymobile's navigation was hijacking the request and sending it via ajax.
Long story short, you can't use ajax for cross-site resource access. There's no way around it that I can find

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the only solution that I have found is to use an hyperlink (as you say in your post). I think that you can't use a ajax request for security reason. However using an hyperlink worked for me and I can authorize my users.

Why don't you use an hyperlink? Is there some problem?

Comment: i would like to have this functionality included in the same place as my other API's

Comment: how to send back the sensitive data like token to the client?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an AJAX request that results in a redirect to Twitter, because authenticating with Twitter means actual user interaction, where the user has to log on to their Twitter account and grant your app access to (parts of) their account.

You're going to either have to change the browsers' location to `/oauth/twitter`, or create a new window with that URL (and signal back to your main window when authentication is done).

Answer (score 0):

Just call your hyperlink in client code.

window.location.href=''