# MEAN: Return to angular app after facebook login on node.js side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

My node.js server is on a different host/port than my web application is serving from and I wish to login using passport + facebook-strategy.

I was able to login from nodejs (assume that the server code is working fine) but I can't seem to find the best way returning to my web application after the login is done:

```
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</a>
```

My first thogugh was go do this AJAX call via the controller in some ng-click function but it didn't work ([and here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910160/passport-angularjs-expressjs-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow))

And now I'm getting a redirection from the server response without having any control on the web application.

This is what happening on the server side:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // res.send("login success?");

    res.status(200).send("Login successfull");
    // res.redirect('/');
  });
```

I hope I'm clear here. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?